# Solr: How distinguish between multiple entities imported through DIH

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

When using DataImportHandler with SqlEntityProcessor, I want to have several definitions going into the same schema with different queries.

How can I search both type of entities but also distinguish their source at the same time. Example:

```
<document>
<entity name="entity1" query="query1">

    <field column="column1" name="column1" />
    <field column="column2" name="column2" />

</entity>
<entity name="entity2" query="query2">

    <field column="column1" name="column1" />
    <field column="column2" name="column2" />

</entity>
</document>
```

How to get data from entity 1 and from entity 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your schema fields (e.g. column1, column2) are compatible between different entities, you can just run DataImportHandler and it will populate Solr collection from both queries.

Then, when you query, you will see all entities combined.

If you want to mark which entity came from which source, I would recommend adding another field (e.g. type) and assigning to it different static values in each entity definition [using TemplateTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#How_would_I_insert_a_static_value_into_a_field_.3F).

Also beware of using clean command. By default it deletes everything from the index. As you are populating the index from several sources, you need to make sure it does not delete too much. Use [preImportDeleteQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Schema_for_the_data_config) to delete only entries with the same value in the type field that you set for that entity.

Comment: I have a problem would you help me? i have indexed with solr a table named items and i have joined it with tables colors, sizes, brands.I want to make a filter for the items ex: black(222), white(137), XXL(225) etc etc.I want simultaneously to display all the items and all the filters.Can i do it with solr?

Comment: concrete example is this http://clevelandwebdesign.org/search/query=YQ== what can you suggest me?

Comment: U can use &fq='color name' if you have the colr in solr index.