# Apache Solr setup for two diffrent projects

Tags: solr, lucene

I just started using apache solr with it's data import functionality on my project
by following steps in http://tudip.blogspot.in/2013/02/install-apache-solr-on-ubuntu.html
 but now I have to make two different instances of my project on same server with different databases but with same configuration of solr for both projects. How can I do that?
Please help me if anyone can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the closest you can get is having two different [Solr cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin). They will run under the same server but will have different configuration (which you can copy paste).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "different databases", do you mean you want to copy from several databases into one join collection/core? If so, you just define multiple entities and possibly multiple datasources in your DataImportHandler config and run either all of them or individually. See [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627953/solr-how-distinguish-between-multiple-entities-imported-through-dih/14629211#14629211) for some tips.

If, on the other hand, you mean different Solr cores/collections, then you just want to run Solr with multiple cores. It is very easy, you just need solr.xml file above your collection level as described [on the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin). Once you get the basics, you may want to look at sharing instance directories and having separate data directories to avoid changing the same config twice (instanceDir vs. dataDir settings on each core).